# How to remove square brackets from a csv file

Tags: python

I am currently working on a machine learning prediction using TensorFlow. To capture the results of the prediction, I have had to use the function 'tolist()' to put them in a column suited for submission. Here is a small sample of the submission file.

```
    ,target_r,target_g,target_b
0,[0.5584068298339844],[0.583054780960083],[0.5836431384086609]

1,[0.5065091848373413],[0.522176206111908],[0.5133420825004578] 

2,[0.48487409949302673],[0.49142706394195557],[0.4913524091243744]

3,[0.4954725503921509],[0.5046894550323486],[0.49923211336135864]

4,[0.4939081370830536],[0.4992391765117645],[0.4986460208892822]
```

As you can see, I need to remove the square brackets. How can I do this using python? Please advise; thanks

Comment: that's copy/pasted directly from the CSV file?

Comment: @Nosa what output do you exactly want?

Comment: can you include example code segments of how your saving the data

Comment: Probably you shouldn't have used tolist() like that.

Comment: So you have that kind of data which you should not have. Why not try something like string.replace("[", "") after reading it line by line.

Comment: Maybe `.tolist()[0]` works. But you need to add some code, expected and obtained output to ensure.

Comment: If it was me, I would write a short script to read line by line and write to second file line by line. `line = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')`. If you can modify the code that writes the CSV, @RodrigoLaguna's suggestion could work.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv("<filename>.csv").iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.replace(r"[\[\]]","",regex=True)).to_csv("<filename>.csv")
```

or

```
open("<filename>.csv", "w").writelines(list(filter(lambda x: x != "", map(lambda x: x.strip().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""),open("<filename>.csv").readlines()))))
```